# Would a person in a gravity well observe the sky as rapidly moving due to time shift?

Tags: gravity, time, popular-science

Inspired by the movie Interstellar (2014) - I was wondering about the crew on the surface of the planet which was deep in the gravity field of the black hole (Gargantua) - if they would look up at the rest of the universe, would they see the stars moving rapidly? Or would there be some relativistic effect on the light reaching them from the universe which would prevent that from happening?

What if they were deeper in that well, would they be able to live to see the end of the universe?

Some clarifications and assumptions:

1. Assume the universe follows the model of the "big bounce" so there's an infinite cycle of expansion and contraction. By "end" of the universe I mean the end of one such cycle.
2. Assume the crew is able to withstand high gravity, and that they get as close as possible without being ripped to shreds.
3. Assume they take a picture of the sky every full orbit around the black hole, so that the section of the sky looked at is always the same. (this is to avoid answers that point to the fact that the sky would change rapidly due to their orbit around the black hole).

Answer (score 1):

We could try this one: People down on that planet got few hours older while people on the ship got twenty years older. So, lets do this. Put a telescope on the surface on that planet and observe motion of people and such in the ship. If you could somehow  do this, you should be able to see everything on the ship happening faster. Also, if people from the ship watched the surface of the planet they should be able to see everything happening slowly. After all, this is what should happen, right? If you could observe the ship up to a point when you return to it you should see everything that happend on the ship happen within your time frame of just a few hours. So yes, I dont see why not. But of course, there is a red shift of the light so if you are deep enough, no one could see you on the surface of the planet.

Comment: So the short answer is yes and there's no relativistic effect that would prevent it?

Answer (score -1):

Let me answer the question with another question.

Would they be able to live long enough to tolerate the high pressure of the highly densed air around the black hole?

Alright, now if they somehow tolerate that pressure and speed, they would never reach the speed of light atleast in their life. So the time passing for them will not be infinite. That's why, they can't see the end of the universe unless it's very near.

They would see the stars moving rapidly if the black hole is rotating. If it isn't rotating then they might see some negligible changes.

Comment: I'm asking in principle - replace humans with a hardened camera capable of withstanding extremely high gravity, with a battery life of 50 years. Also I am assuming a case of "big bounce" so when I say end I mean the next bounce. Also assume a picture is taken every one orbit of the black hole so the section of the sky being looked at is constant.